# Using The Datasource Property

Tags: c#, gridview, dataset, drop-down-menu, properties

I have a dropdownlist and a function that returns a certain DataSet.

Can I call that function in the datasource property at the designer? If not, how do I use that property in the designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using Windows Form, dropdownlist is Combobox. Am I right ?

[image]

Put Combobox in your form

[image]

Click on pointer гn the left top corner of a Combobox 
Check "Use Data Bound Items"
[image]

Select Data Source and Display Member (one of the field of table in your database)
For example:
[image]